# Compact Embedding Theorem. Metric Space. Santambrogio. (reference request).

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

In the book `Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians' by Santambrogio, on page 289 it is written that [image]

In this setup, the space $X=(X,d)$ is a metric space, $\{\tilde{x}^\tau\}_{\tau>0}$ is a sequence such that for each $t \in[0,T]$, $\tilde{x}^\tau(t)\in X$, and $|(\tilde{x}^\tau)'|(t)$ is the metric derivative.

$\textbf{Question :}$ Does anyone know where I can find a reference of this specific embedding theorem?

EDIT : I realized the problem, if the underlying space $\Omega$ is assumed to be compact then compactness is straightforward (this is the case in Santambrogios book). If however we are working on a non-compact set, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^d$ then compactness with this method is only achieved in $W_p$ for $1\leq p <2$. The equicontinuity + the compactness give the uniform convergence in whatever space we have the compactness.

Comment: Let $f\colon[0,T]\to X$ be an absolutely continuous curve. Then $d(f(x),f(y))$ is no greater than the integral of the derivative, which is no greater than $C^{1/2}\lvert x-y\rvert^{1/2}$ by Cauchy–Schwarz.